# NSFetchedResultsController not work in Release mode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I develop a app using coredata.

But, in AdHoc or Release mode , cannot get data from coredata(using NSFetchedResultsController).
In Debug mode, can get data.

look followin code.

```
NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:MODEL_NAME] ;
[req setFetchBatchSize:20] ;
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"orderIndex" ascending:YES];
[req setSortDescriptors:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]] ;
NSFetchedResultsController *res = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:req managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil] ;
NSAssert([res performFetch:nil], @"Fetch failed") ;
int dataCounter = [[[res sections] objectAtIndex:0] numberOfObjects] ;
// In Release mode:0, in Debug mode:2
NSLog(@"dataCounter:%d",dataCounter) ;
```

I change Release or Debug mode , like this way.
Produce > Schema > Edit Scheme > Run > Build Configuration.

Env:Xcode 4.6.3 , Base SDK iOS 6.1

Do you have any help ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should use the `error:` parameter of `performFetch:` and print the error if the fetch fails.

Comment: Doesmit throw an exception? What is it?

Comment: thanks your response.
No error and no exception. Just 0 data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSAssert([res performFetch:&error], @"Fetch failed") ;
```

This code is wrong.

I setting Other C/C++ Flags "-DNS_BLOCKS_ASSERTIONS=1" in Release mode. this flag is to remove NSAssert line.
So, performFetch is not exec.

thank you.